# Finding the complexity of the given algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Hi I have no idea to calculate the complexity. So if any one help me find the answer it will be great. ( Also try to write how you calculated it)

Find out the complexity of the following algorithm:

```
function min (X1, X2…………Xn)
  min = X1;

  for i = 2 to n 
    if (min > Xi) then 
      min = Xi;
```

Comment: Linear time complexity, `O(n)`. Function `min` performs `n - 1` operations (comparisons), that's why we have `O(n - 1) = O(n)`

Comment: Then there's [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Sir, can you please show me the time for each line and also the calculation? It will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @Antony Aiwin K X: I've provided both timings and solution, hope, that they will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from *timings*:

```
function min (X1, X2…………Xn)
  min = X1;             # const_1
  
  for i = 2 to n        # n - 1 times 
    if (min > Xi) then  #   const_2
      min = Xi;         #   const_1 (if min > Xi), 0 (if min <= Xi)
```

So for the **worst** (when `X1..Xn` sorted in descending order) case we  have execution time `T`

```
T = const_1 + (n - 1) * (const_2 + const_1)
```

For the **best** case (when `X1` is the minimum)

```
T = const_1 + (n - 1) * (const_2)
```

We can combine these cases together and have

```
T = const_1 + (n - 1) * (const_2 + p * const_1)

where p - some value in 0..1 range (0 - best, 1 - worst case)
```

In any case we have a *linear formula* for execution time `T`

```
T = A + n * B
```

where `A` and `B` some constant values. Or for *complexity* `O(T)`:

```
O(T) = O(A + n * B) = O(A) + O(B * n) = O(B * n) = B * O(n) = O(n)
```